# whats wrogn with my ipv6 UDP connection in C language?

Tags: c, udp, ipv6

I am a noob trying to establish an easy UDP connection between a client and a server using Ipv6 and C-Language.

Apparently, the sendto() function is returning 1 (failure), but to be honest I don't really understand it at all.

If someone wants to look at it and help it would be greatly appreciated!

thank you. alex

```
//Server

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS


#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <in6addr.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>



#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")




int startWinsock(void)
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa);
}



#define IN6AADR_ANY_INIT {{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}}
struct in6_addr anyaddr = IN6AADR_ANY_INIT;

int main()
{



    printf("this is the Server. \n \n");
    long rc;
    int socket_fd;
    char buf[256];
    char buf2[300];
    struct sockaddr_in6 remoteAddr;
    int remoteAddrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
    struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr, client_addr;

    rc = startWinsock();
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        printf("error: startWinsock, error code: %d\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Winsock started!\n");
    }

    //UDP Socket creation
    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("error creating socket, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("UDP Socket erstellt!\n");
    }

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

    server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    server_addr.sin6_port = htons(50000);




    rc = bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("error: bind, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket bind to Port 50.000 \n");
    }
    while (1)
    {
        socklen_t clilen = sizeof(client_addr);
        rc = recvfrom(socket_fd, buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &clilen);
        if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Error: recvfrom, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d Bytes received!\n", rc);
            buf[rc] = '\0';
        }
        printf("recieved data: %s\n", buf);
        //Answer
        sprintf(buf2, "Du mich auch %s", buf);
        rc = sendto(socket_fd, buf2, strlen(buf2), 0, (struct sockaddr_in6*)&remoteAddr, remoteAddrLen);
        if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Error: sendto, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d Bytes sent!\n", rc);
        }
    }
    return 0;



}
```

```
//Client

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <in6addr.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>



#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define SERVADDR "127.0.0.1"
//"fe80::e7:edbf:1df6:7451%5"

int startWinsock(void)
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa);
}



int main()
{

    printf("this is the client. \n \n");

    long rc;
    int socket_fd;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr, client_addr;
    char buf[256];
    char addrbuf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];



    rc = startWinsock();
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        printf("error: startWinsock, error code: %d\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Winsock started!\n");
    }

    //UDP Socket creation
    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("error creating socket, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("UDP Socket created!\n");
    }

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

    // addr prepatation
    server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, SERVADDR, &server_addr.sin6_addr);
    server_addr.sin6_port = htons(50000);


    while (1)
    {
        printf("insert text: ");
        gets(buf);
        rc = sendto(socket_fd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
        if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("error: sendto, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d Bytes sent!\n", rc);
        }

        rc = recvfrom(socket_fd, buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clilen);
        if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("error: recvfrom, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d Bytes received!\n", rc);
            buf[rc] = '\0';
            printf("received data: %s\n", buf);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `sendto()` returns `1`, this means that one byte was sent, it is not an error condition. Do you mean `-1`? What is the error code?

Comment: "_trying to establish an easy UDP connection between a client and a server_" UDP is  explicitly connectionless, so you cannot establish a UDP connection. UDP sends without establishing a connection, and it has no idea, and simply doesn't care, whether the data are received on the other end. TCP is connection-oriented, and it must first establish a connection, and it checks to see if the data are received on the other end.

Comment: @RonMaupin Well, it sorta cares if the other end receives the packets; if the peer signals, that the port is closed (icmp port unreachable), then subsequent sends will fail with "connection refused".

Comment: @Ctx, the actual ICMP error message from the destination will be Type 3 (Destination Unreachable) Code 3 (Port Unreachable).  If the host reports "connection refused", it is really the wrong error message. That could be an artifact of the OS or the programming library.

Comment: @RonMaupin "Connection refused" is the error code that the `send()` function family will return.

Comment: @Ctx, if that function reported the correct error (port unreachable) to the application, the application could then take appropriate action. It seems the function is simply reporting a generic error when it encounters an ICMP error message. I would certainly want to know the correct error, even when using TCP, but it seems that it is simply lumping different errors into one generic message.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `#define SERVADDR "127.0.0.1"` for IPv6?

Comment: @RonMaupin UDP sockets report "connection refused" when an error  was received for a packet associated to this socket. If you need further error information you can use `IP_RECVERR` on linux, which provides extended error information for such cases, but usually, a "did not work" is sufficient in many cases.

Comment: In the client, as @Gerhardh said, `127.0.0.1` is not a valid `AF_INET6` address so `inet_pton` should have returned an error and `sendto` will be sending to an all-zeroes address. Also, `sendto` in the Server sends to `remoteAddr`, but `remoteAddr` is never initialised to any value.  Sending to `clientAddr` would make more sense.